# Image as a submit button

Tags: asp.net-mvc, image, oauth-2.0, form-submit

I'm changing the buttons to images which are used for `OAuth` (see [oauth2](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-facebook-and-google-oauth2-and-openid-sign-on) tutorial).
I'm also grayscaling those images, and for this I use [this](http://solemone.de/code/code-examples/demos-grayscale-hover-effect-with-html5-canvas-and-jquery/) code.

This is my _ExternalLoginsPartial.cshtml:

```
@{
var loginProviders = Context.GetOwinContext().Authentication.GetExternalAuthenticationTypes();

string action = Model.Action;
string returnUrl = Model.ReturnUrl;
using (Html.BeginForm(action, "Account", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    foreach (AuthenticationDescription p in loginProviders)
    {
        <ul class="imglist" id="socialLogin">
            @if (p.AuthenticationType == "Google")
            {
                <li><a href="#"><img src="/Content/google.png" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="/Content/google.png" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="/Content/google.png" /></a></li>
            }
            @if (p.AuthenticationType == "Microsoft")
            {
                <li><a href="#"><img src="/Content/outlook.jpg" /></a></li>
            }
            @if (p.AuthenticationType == "Facebook")
            {
                <li><a href="#"><img src="/Content/facebook.png" /></a></li>
            }
        </ul>
    }
}
}
```

I can't remove the `<a href="#">` because that will break the grayscaling.
And I can't place a `button` tag inside it, because that is bad `HTML` (compiler complains about it if done so).

So how can I turn these images to act like a submit button?

EDIT:
http://i61.tinypic.com/2ns7t00.png

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can replace the anchor element with a button element but you will have to change the code a little:

```
<button type="submit"><img src="..."></button>
```

Then change the selectors in the code:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('button img').each(function() {
        ...
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("button").hover(
        ...
    );
});
```

If you want to get rid of the button styles, just use css:

```
button {
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
}
```

Comment: I liked your approach and worked great. However, the button has some styles set I don't want it to have. Any idea how to remove all that? Inspecting it with dev tools, turned everything off, the gray background behind the first image was still there. See my question with picture.

Comment: When I accepted it, I fixed it almost exactly like that. Just added an extra style: `background-color:white;`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could submit the form with Javascript by clicking on a link:

```
using (Html.BeginForm(action, "Account", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, id = "myId" }))
{
   <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('myId').submit();">
       <img src="/Content/facebook.png" />
   </a>
}
```

This is just sample code for how you could add an id to the form and add a click event on the link.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. The problem with your approach is that the `a` tag doesn't have the property `value` which is needed to pass on the provider like in this code: `<button type="submit" id="@p.AuthenticationType" name="provider" value="@p.AuthenticationType>`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like `<input type="image" src="submit.gif">` which will submit your page within the form tag. An alternative would be to use jQuery and create a click event for the image.

Answer (score 0):

As you specified in a response to another question, you wanted to return a value as well you could do this instead: (based off of Kevin's Answer)

```
using (Html.BeginForm(action, "Account", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, id = "myId" }))
{
   <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('@p.AuthenticationType').click();">
       <img src="/Content/facebook.png" />
   </a>
<input name ="provider" type="submit" style="display:none;" id="@p.AuthenticationType" value="@p.AuthenticationType" />
}
```